# Pegando valores de array PHP

Tags: php, html

Boa tarde. Como eu faço para pegar somente um array que conter minha condição?
Estou refazendo a pergunta poís ainda não consegui, mas estou colocando todo meu código.

```
<?php 
            include 'inc/cabecalho.php';
            include 'inc/menu.php'; 
            include 'script/script.php';
            $e = new Script(); 

            foreach ($e->listarLivros() as $livro){ 

             $a = 0;

             foreach ($e->listarAutores() as $autor){
              $a = $autor['idAutor'];
            }
            ?>

            <div class="col-md-4">
              <div class="card card-product card-plain no-shadow" data-colored-shadow="false">
                <div class="card-header card-header-image">
                  <a href="product.html">
                    <img src="<?=$livro['fotoCapa']?>" style="width: 260px; height: 350px;">
                  </a>
                </div>
                <div class="card-body text-center">
                  <a href="#">
                    <h4 class="card-title"><?=$livro['titulo']?></h4>
                  </a>
                  <p class="description">
                    <?=$a?>
                  </p>
                  <p class="description">
                    <?=$livro['id_editora']?>
                  </p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

          <?php }  ?>
```

Abaixo seria onde eu pego os dados em uma classe -

```
    <?php 

class Script
{   
    public $editora     = array();
    public $autor       = array();
    public $livros      = array();
    public $base_livros = base_livros;
    public $base_autor  = base_autor;

    public function listarEditoras()
    {
        $this->editora  = array
        (
            '1' => array
            (
                'idEditora' => '1', 
                'editora'   => 'Editora Viseu', 
                'endereco'  => 'Av. Duque de Caxias, 882, Maringá - PR', 
                'email'     => 'contato@editoraviseu.com', 
            ),  
            '2' => array
            (
                'idEditora' => '2', 
                'editora'   => 'Editora Harper Colllins', 
                'endereco'  => 'Av. Duque de Caxias, 882, Maringá - PR', 
                'email'     => 'faleconosco@harpercollins.com.br', 
            ),  
            '3' => array
            (
                'idEditora' => '3', 
                'editora'   => 'Editora Schoba', 
                'endereco'  => 'Av. Brg. Faria Lima, 1811 - 918, São Paulo - SP', 
                'email'     => 'atendimento@editoraschoba.com.br', 
            ),
        );

        return $this->editora;
    }

    public function listarAutores()
    {
        $this->autor  = array
        (
            '1' => array
            (
                'idAutor'  => '1', 
                'autor'    => 'Oswaldo Tognetta', 
                'formacao' => 'Contador', 
                'foto'     => $this->base_autor.'oswaldo_tognetta.jpg', 
            ),  
            '2' => array
            (
                'idAutor'  => '2', 
                'autor'    => 'Josué Ribeiro', 
                'formacao' => 'Segurança do Trabalho', 
                'foto'     => $this->base_autor.'josue_ribeiro.jpg', 
            ),  
            '3' => array
            (
                'idAutor'  => '3', 
                'autor'    => 'Edson Reinaldo', 
                'formacao' => 'Metalúrgico', 
                'foto'     => $this->base_autor.'edson_reinaldo.jpg', 
            ),          
            '4' => array
            (
                'idAutor'  => '4', 
                'autor'    => 'Lisa Genova', 
                'formacao' => 'Oradora', 
                'foto'     => $this->base_autor.'lisa_genova.png', 
            ),          
            '5' => array
            (
                'idAutor'  => '5', 
                'autor'    => 'Dave Asprey', 
                'formacao' => 'Empreendedor', 
                'foto'     => $this->base_autor.'dave_asprey.jpg', 
            ),          
            '6' => array
            (
                'idAutor'  => '6', 
                'autor'    => 'Maureen Johnson', 
                'formacao' => 'Escritora', 
                'foto'     => $this->base_autor.'maureen_johnson.jpg', 
            ),          
            '7' => array
            (
                'idAutor'  => '7', 
                'autor'    => 'Amauri Salvador', 
                'formacao' => 'Letras', 
                'foto'     => $this->base_autor.'amauri_salvador.jpg', 
            ),          
            '8' => array
            (
                'idAutor'  => '8', 
                'autor'    => 'Jucelino de Sales', 
                'formacao' => 'Letras', 
                'foto'     => $this->base_autor.'jucelino_de_sales.jpg', 
            ),
        );

        return $this->autor;
    }

    public function listarLivros()
    {
        $this->livros  = array
        (
            '1' => array
            (
                'idLivro'  => '1', 
                'titulo'    => 'Uma venda na beira da estrada', 
                'totalPaginas' => '258', 
                'edicao' => '1',
                'isbn' => '9788530006358',
                'ano' => '2019',
                'fotoCapa' => $this->base_livros.'uma_venda_na_beira_da_estrada.png', 
                'id_editora' => '1',
                'id_autor' => '1',
            ),          
            '2' => array
            (
                'idLivro'  => '2', 
                'titulo'    => 'Memórias de um contabilista', 
                'totalPaginas' => '542', 
                'edicao' => '1',
                'isbn' => '9788530006556',
                'ano' => '2019',
                'fotoCapa' => $this->base_livros.'memorias_de_um_contabilista.jpg', 
                'id_editora' => '1',
                'id_autor' => '1',
            ),          
            '3' => array
            (
                'idLivro'  => '3', 
                'titulo'    => 'Depressão profunda sobrevivi!', 
                'totalPaginas' => '116', 
                'edicao' => '1',
                'isbn' => '9788554549756',
                'ano' => '2018',
                'fotoCapa' => $this->base_livros.'depressao_profunda_sobrevivi.jpg', 
                'id_editora' => '1',
                'id_autor' => '2',
            ),
        );

        return $this->livros;       
    }
}
```

O que eu preciso é assim. Quando o id_autor for igual ao idAutor pegar o nome dele. Porém não estou conseguindo via foreach.

Comment: Nesse caso eu sempre coloco o idEditora como chave do array para poder buscar. Veja se é possível alterar a estrutura do seu array.

Comment: A entendi. Vou testar todas opções.

Answer (score 4):

Você pode usar o array_search com array_column.

o `array_column` vai separar os valores do idEditora,

e o `array_search` vai pegar o indice do array que você está procurando

```
$key = array_search('1', array_column($editoras, 'idEditora'));
$result = $array[$key];
```

Caso você queira mais de um registro do array, você pode usar o `array_filter`

```
$result = array_filter($editoras, function ($row) {
    return $row['idEditora'] == '1';
});
```

Comment: Desconhecia as funções, vou testa-las

Comment: Sim eu gostaria de todos os campos do array cujo id seja 1. Isso meio que estou emulando uma tabela do banco de dados. Seria um trabalho em que pediram que todos os registros ficassem em array. Depois dessa 'tabela' vou ter outras com relação a essa, por exemplo na outra tabela de livros vai ter la idEditora, dai ao listar quero pegar essa informações da editora cujo id esteva no livro.

Answer (score 2):

Use um foreach para varrer o array e um if para verificar cada array dentro do array maior

```
foreach ($editora as $editora) {

    //substitua o '1' pelo valor que achar melhor
    if($editora['idEditora'] == '1'){
        var_dump($editora);
    }

}
```